# Eclipse incorrectly generating new Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am attempting to create an android project through eclipse as I have many other times, but today Im having a strange problem. After choosing new project - Android project - setting my name and target SDK - icon/empty activity etc. When I have to name the empty activity I enter a name and if I click Finish nothing happens and the name activity menu stays there. The next button is greyed out.

[image: 1]

The only thing I can do is cancel out from there. In my project explorer the project HAS been created though. There are no src files, no activity or anything really. A small manifest file and some empty resource files.

[image: 1]

Im not familiar with the icons associated with these files and folders. I dont know why this is happening. I have tried "Help" -> "Install new software" and install from url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ and have also tried updating and install all current SDK's but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Comment: Will you specify your version of Eclipse and the ADT Plugin?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay in response. The version of Eclipse I am using is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

and the ADT is Android Development Toolkit

Version: 23.0.3.1327240